# Cosmos DB NoSQL (NodeJS/Javascript): How to readAll() but for specific attributes only? Not the entire object

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Let's say I have below documents inside my Cosmos DB (NoSQL) container:

```
[
  {
    "id": "isaacnewton",
    "fullname": "Isaac Newton",
    "dob": "04011643",
    "country": "United Kingdom"
  },
  {
    "id": "alberteinstein",
    "fullname": "Albert Einstein",
    "dob": "14031879",
    "country": "Germany"
  },
  ...
]
```

Say, I have like about 10000 of them.

In order to read all the documents from the container, currently I know the basic usage of `readAll()`, which is:

```
const { resources: allItems } = await container.items.readAll().fetchAll();
```

But it returns all the attributes/fields from the documents (objects). Even the unwanted system attributes like `_rid`, `_self`, `_etag`, etc are there in the response.

### Question

**While using the `readAll()` function**, *not the `query()` function*, how do I specify which certain attributes/fields that I want in the response? Can I only receive "id" and "fullname" only?

Expecting the outcome to be like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "isaacnewton",
    "fullname": "Isaac Newton"
  },
  {
    "id": "alberteinstein",
    "fullname": "Albert Einstein"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Which package are you using? are you referring to fetchAll?

Comment: @Sajeetharan as long as I can still use `readAll()`, I don't mind pairing it with `fetchAll()` or anything else possible.

Comment: I'm curious to know the package version

Comment: What can't you use `query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three fundamental ways to retrieve documents from a container:

- Read a single document from a container (providing the document's ID and partition-key value). This always returns all properties.
- Query a container for documents (with a SQL query, along with either a partition-key value or a cross-partition query signal, and optionally max # of documents to return). You get to choose which properties you want.
- Read "all documents" from a container (you may optionally limit this by specifying max # of documents). Just like a single-read, this returns full documents with all properties, but as an array of documents.

Your call to `ReadAll()` is going to return you an array of documents, with every property of those documents.

The only way to filter properties for your returned documents is with a *query*; there's no ability to do this for a single read, or for a read-all-documents operation (you can even look at the underlying [get a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document) and  [list documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents) REST API details, which is what `Read()` and `ReadAll()` ultimately map to).

Ok, there is one more approach: you can do property-filtering client-side after returning an array of documents, but you will still be transmitting full documents from Cosmos DB to your client application.

Comment: Yeah, I had just came to understand that `readAll()` doesn't allow us to specify the return attributes/fields.

Answer (score -2):

`ReadAll()` method reads the entire document.

You can use `for` loop to fetch specific properties from the output of `ReadAll()` method.

Below is sample code - (Here I have declared two variables id and name and assigned their values inside for loop). This all processing is done on client-side.

```
const { resources } = await  container.items.readAll().fetchAll();

var  id, name ;

for (const  item  of  resources) {
id = item.id;
name = item.fullname;
console.log(`${item.id}: ${item.name}`);
}
```

**Output**

```
 "isaacnewton" : "Isaac Newton"
```

Comment: I know that by using the `query()` function, we can specify which fields we want int he result. But as I specifically described in my question, using the `query()` function is not what I'm looking for. Then, in this case, we're only left with `readAll()` function and looks like we cannot limit which fields to return in the results.

Comment: @夏期劇場 I have updated my answer. Yes you are correct. The option left is `readAll()` to fetch complete document on client-side and the using loop one can read/display required properties.